# Transform text file : how to?

Tags: etl

I have a text file with 85 fields , comma separated. 
I need to produce a different text file with only 25 fields. 
The first option i've thought is to import that file in a database, then re-export only the fields i need.

What are other tool / option I can use ?

Does exists some command-line tool (Windows) to transform a text file without going through database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Powershell Script (Microsoft). Please see also https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee176874.aspx

Create a text file with the following content:

```
Name,Department,Title
Pilar Ackerman,Research,Manager
Jonathan Haas,Finance,Finance Specialist
Ken Myer,Finance,Accountant
```

The following command extracts all infomrmation and filters for department = Finance

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\test.txt | Where-Object {$_.department -eq "Finance"} 

Name           Department   Title                                                  
----           ----------   -----                                                  
Jonathan Haas  Finance      Finance Specialist                                     
Ken Myer       Finance      Accountant
```

This commands accesses specific columns

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter (",") -Header "Name","Department","Title" -Path c:\temp\test.txt | SELECT {$_.Title + " " + $_.Name + " " + $_.Department }

$_.Title + " " + $_.Name + " " + $_.Department
-----------------------------------------------
Title Name Department
Manager Pilar Ackerman Research
Finance Specialist Jonathan Haas Finance
Accountant Ken Myer Finance
```

You can, of course,  also save the result in a new file.